# Modifying variables based on MQTT payloads for Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: python, mqtt, iot, paho

So, I'm trying to modify a PWM signal based on message payloads sent from an MQTT broker.
My client code looks like this:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt #import the client1
import RPi.GPIO as g
############

g.setmode(g.BCM)  
g.setup(24, g.OUT)
p= g.PWM(24, 1)
p.start(10)

#Recibimos esta confirmacion cuando recibimos respuesta de conexion con el servidor
freq=1
duty=10

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):  ##Creamos la funcion 'on_connect'
    print("Connected with result code " +str(rc))
#Una vez conectados, nos suscribimos a los topicos
    client.subscribe("CoreElectronics/test")  #suscripcion a test
#Cada uno de estos topics debe mandarnos un mensaje, en este caso
    #'test' nos devuelve 'Hello'
    #'topic' nos devuelve 'World!'

##Recibimos esta confirmacion cuando nos llega un mensaje del servidor

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):     #Creamos la funcion 'on_message'
    msg.payload=msg.payload.decode("utf-8")
    print(msg.topic+ " " +str(msg.payload))

    if msg.payload == "f":  #Respuesta del primer topic
        freq= freq+2
        p.ChangeFrequency(freq)
        print("Recieved Frequency increment, LED frequency is now: ", freq)


    if msg.payload == "d": #Respuesta del segundo topic
        if freq==1:
            freq=freq
            print('The frequency is minimal!')
        else:
            freq= freq-2
            print("Recieved Frequency decrement, LED frequency is now: ", freq)
            p.ChangeFrequency(freq)

    if msg.payload == "l": #Respuesta del segundo topic
        if duty==100:
            duty=duty
            print('The Duty Cycle is maximum!')
        else:
            duty= duty+10
            p.ChangeDutyCycle(duty)
            print("Recieved Duty Cycle increment, LED duty is now: ", duty)


    if msg.payload == "k": #Respuesta del segundo topic
        if duty==1:
            duty=duty
            duty()
            print('The Duty Cycle is minimal!')
        else:
            duty=duty-10
            duty()
            p.ChangeDutyCycle(duty)
            print("Recieved Duty Cycle decrement, LED duty is now: ", duty)

#Creamos un cliente MQTT y le adjuntamos rutinas

client = mqtt.Client()  #Aqui creamos un cliente de mqtt, llamado 'client'
freq=freq
duty=duty
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect("mqtt.eclipse.org", 1883,60) # Nos conectamos a esta direccion
client.loop_forever()  #El cliente se ejecutara indefinidamente
```

And my publisher looks like this:

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
while 1: publish.single("CoreElectronics/test", input(), hostname= "mqtt.eclipse.org")
```

The gist of these programs is for me to send character inputs from the Broker to the Client in order to change the values of 'freq' and 'duty' to control the PWM that feeds an LED. Sadly, to no avail. The Client program only prints:

```
CoreElectronics/test f #this last character changing depending on the broker input. Be it: f, d, l or k
```

Comment: `p` is not in scope in your `on_message` callback function

Comment: Could you help me know how to declare it? I've tried to declare it in the on_message function as `p=g.PWM(24, freq)` but it still behaves the same.

Comment: You need to look at the `global` python keyword